# React router route change does not work on iphone 6 ios 10

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to change route programmatically. However, only iphone 6 ios 10 does not work code below

1. `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'; browserHistory.push("/" + route);`
2. `this.props.history.push('/' + route);`
3. `window.location.href = route; // cannot use this though..`

I tried 3 of them. It works with all other ios devices from iphone 5 or iphone 6 ios8.

Anyone solved this problem?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Safari !

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this issue?